# MS Teams permissions for creating a group

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Can someone help me understand how to add a permission to a MS-Graph API call?

I'm trying to create a new team/group but I'm getting a permission error. Obviously I need add the **Team.Create** permission if I want to create a Team. Which I did as seen in the image below

[image: Azure Active Directory - permission added]

Here's the sample code where I tried to add the permission to the MSAL client request:

```
    // Initialize Graph client
    const client = graph.Client.init({
        // Implement an auth provider that gets a token
        // from the app's MSAL instance
        authProvider: async (done) => {
            try {
                // Get the user's account
                const account = await msalClient
                    .getTokenCache()
                    .getAccountByHomeId(userId);

                let scope = process.env.OAUTH_SCOPES.split(',');
                scope.push("Team.Create");
                console.log("Added a extra permission request");
                console.log("scope = " + scope);

                if (account) {
                    // Attempt to get the token silently
                    // This method uses the token cache and
                    // refreshes expired tokens as needed
                    const response = await msalClient.acquireTokenSilent({
                        scopes: scope,
                        redirectUri: process.env.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
                        account: account
                    });
                    console.log("\nResponse scope = " + JSON.stringify(response) + "\n");

                    // First param to callback is the error,
                    // Set to null in success case
                    done(null, response.accessToken);
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err)));
                done(err, null);
            }
        }
    });

    return client;
```

Then I get the following error:
*The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxxxxx'
named 'Node.js Graph Tutorial'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource*

I did give permissions to **Team.Create** in the *Azure Active Directory*, so how do I consent to this app gaining access? Note this code is the tutorial for learning Graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the screenshot, you can't give admin consent to the permission as it is grayed out.
You'll need to try if you can grant user consent.

`acquireTokenSilent` won't work in this case since consent is needed.
You need to use one of the interactive authentication methods to trigger user authentication, at which time you can consent to the permission on your user's behalf.

In that sample specifically, you probably need to modify the scopes here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-nodeexpressapp/blob/08cc363e577b41dde4f6a72ad465439af20f4c3a/demo/graph-tutorial/routes/auth.js#L11.
And then trigger the /signin route in your browser.

Comment: Juunas! You are a star! That did the trick. Thank you so much for helping